# Should in a REST API the data sent from the client through PUT be the same as a call to GET?

Tags: rest

I am defining a (hopefully) RESTful API. When someone puts /person/{name}. I was thinking of returning something different than what was put in. For example links in the data for the /group he is part of?

How important is idempotence in REST?

Comment: all rest is telling you is to send back a response with the proper status code like 200 or else when the request is executed successfully. Whatever you put in the body is your problem but sending some random data after a put is not really restfull. The client should to a get to query something.

Comment: There is no need to. Just imagine a client creating new person records, as in your example. Information like `creationTime` or `createdBy` is something the server adds to the record. So a `GET` can return this information, whereas a client `PUT` should not have it (the client can be tainted, the server usually is not).

Comment: Just to be clear, when talking about idempotence in REST we usually talking about the operation and not what is returned back. PUT has to be idempotent <=> when you PUT the same information several times, it will have the same effect and no other side effect.

Comment: Thanks fshehat, that was indeed my confusion..